# Are there any CAs that can issue SSL certificates with extra EKUs?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

I need an SSL certificate with a few extra uncommon EKUs (i.e. 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2, "IPSec Intermediate System Usage"). Self-signed certificate is not an option. Does anybody know about any CAs that allow additional EKUs? I contacted Namecheap, Comodo and Godaddy, and all of them replied that they cannot issue one.

Comment: Why is self signed not an option? Is an enterprise CA een option?

Comment: I don't want users to be forced to install my root certificate. Thus, I'd prefer to have a certificate signed by a recognized CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) from the CA/Browser Forum are rather strict about inceluding *extendedKeyUsage* values in a certificate which are non-standard. While it is not completely forbidden, the wording is such, that a CA will usually want to avoid the hassle (see section 7.1.2.4).

Some Root Stores (Microsoft) even require of CAs to explicitely state all possible EKU values in advance, that a root or intermediate certificate might sign.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the requirements! Well, that apparently means that what I was intending to do is all but impossible.

Comment: Probably. And even if you really find a CA, it would probably be VERY expensive.